# Spark sql to do a excel transpose paste

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a couple of scenarios to convert multiple rows into comma separated single column and in another scenario I have a comma separated column which I have to insert as multiple rows. I use spark scala.

### Scenario 1

```
Select names from employee where role = 'Engineer'
```

1. Mark
2. Steve
3. Krishna

I need to convert it as Mark, Steve, Krishna.

### Scenario 2

I have the same Mark, Steve, Krishna which I need to insert as 3 rows.

Any help?

Comment: Try use mkString(", ") like val names= Array("Mark", "Steve", "Krishna") names.mkString(", ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Scenario 2, you can try something like this

```
select name as value from table union select ename from table
```

You will have to make it dynamic though.